# Make scrollbar track transparent in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, sass, scrollbar

I've managed to customise the scrollbar of a list that works in Chrome, Safari and Edge, however in Firefox, the track still appears. It seems that Firefox doesn't support ::webkit-scrollbar so does anyone have any suggestions on how to make the track transparent/invisible?

[image: Track in Firefox]

[image: Track in Chrome (Desired output)]

Comment: https://codepen.io/reacraf/pen/ExaBZzZ - Take a look at this, it seems the scrollbar-color takes 2 arguments: The color of the bar and the background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```css
.scrollbar {
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scrollbar-color: grey transparent;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 6px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollbar">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer elementum semper tortor at pellentesque. Suspendisse iaculis quis risus in sagittis. Vestibulum elementum pulvinar vulputate. Morbi rutrum nisl eget finibus efficitur. Donec sed pellentesque purus. Nam vel euismod quam. Quisque lobortis aliquet nibh nec placerat. Maecenas volutpat orci dolor, mollis elementum tortor efficitur malesuada.Ut elementum sagittis lorem, non tempus diam euismod eu. Nullam vel diam ornare, aliquet enim non, sodales nulla. Pellentesque molestie, felis id pellentesque mattis, purus metus ultrices ipsum, vitae tristique nunc ante a odio. Quisque malesuada, felis sed tempor feugiat, est ante hendrerit sem, a porta elit metus ac est. Nullam sed felis leo. Donec ac vehicula dolor. Duis vel lacus volutpat, congue leo et, congue ex. Nullam rhoncus orci ut odio rutrum, id hendrerit elit malesuada. Curabitur orci neque, mollis ut aliquam a, dictum vitae massa. Donec efficitur ornare varius. Aliquam vulputate pharetra tortor nec finibus.


</div>
```